# Nomad : failed to call the Nomad list policies API: Unexpected response code: 403 (Permission denied)

Tags: hashicorp, nomad

I have a nomad autoscaler job, but upon checking its logs it shows like this.

`[ERROR] policy_manager: encountered an error monitoring policy IDs: error="failed to call the Nomad list policies API: Unexpected response code: 403 (Permission denied)"`

where my nomad job is

```
job "autoscaler-test" {
  datacenters = ["test"]

  meta {
    "nomad-control-token" = "f418583e-4cd9-545a-b0b9-36e1cd10bf32"
  }

  group "autoscaler-test" {
    count = 1

    network {
      port "http" {
        to = 8080
      }
    }

  constraint {
    attribute = "${node.class}"
    value = "test-apps"
  }


    task "autoscaler" {
      driver = "docker"

      config {
        image = "hashicorp/nomad-autoscaler:0.3.7"
        command = "nomad-autoscaler"
        args = [
          "agent",
          "-config",
          "${NOMAD_TASK_DIR}/config.hcl",
          "-http-bind-address",
          "0.0.0.0",
          "-policy-dir",
          "${NOMAD_TASK_DIR}/policies/"
        ]
        ports = ["http"]
      }

      template {
      data = <<EOF
      nomad {
        address = "http://{{env "attr.unique.network.ip-address" }}:4646"
        skip_verify = true
      }
      apm "nomad-apm" {
        driver = "nomad-apm"
      }
      target "aws-asg" {
        driver = "aws-asg"
        config = {
          # aws_access_key_id = "AKIAV4V5C5ULL23GWN6K"
          # aws_secret_access_key = "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"
          aws_region = "ap-northeast-3"
        }
      }
      strategy "target-value" {
        driver = "target-value"
      }
      EOF
        destination = "${NOMAD_TASK_DIR}/config.hcl"
      }

      template {
        data = <<EOF
        scaling "cluster_policy" {
          enabled = true
          min = 0
          max = 3
          policy {
            cooldown = "2m"
            evaluation_interval = "1m"
            check "cpu_allocated_percentage" {
              source = "nomad-apm"
              query = "percentage-allocated_cpu"
              query_window = "5m"
              strategy "target-value" {
                target = 70
              }
            }
            check "memory_allocated_percentage" {
              source = "nomad-apm"
              query = "percentage-allocated_memory"
              query_window = "2m"
              strategy "target-value" {
                target = 70
              }
            }
            target "aws-asg" {
              dry-run = "false"
              aws_asg_name = "asg-test"
              node_class = "test-apps"
              node_drain_deadline = "5m"
              node_purge = "true"
              node_drain_ignore_system_jobs = "false"
            }
          }
        }
        EOF
        destination = "${NOMAD_TASK_DIR}/policies/hashistack.hcl"
      }

      resources {
        cpu    = 50
        memory = 128
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If acl are enabled, you have to pass nomad token when accesing nomad. For example https://github.com/hashicorp/nomad-autoscaler/blob/6c77b0170fa9a52f249255e055b5963f02e4f0d3/command/agent.go#L118 .